# Can Liz Cheney run as an independent in the general election?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, republican-primary

Liz Cheney has lost her primary race to be re-nominated for her seat as Wyoming’s representative in the House. Harriet Hageman, a pro-Trump candidate, will be the Republican nominee in November.

All news coverage has made it seem like Cheney will definitely be leaving Congress when her current term is over, for example today’s Washington Post headline is [“Cheney says she is considering a White House run after drubbing in Wyo. primary”](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2022/08/16/wyoming-liz-cheney-alaska-primaries/).

Why isn’t Cheney planning to keep her seat by running as an independent? Does Wyoming law prevent her from doing so, or does she simply think it would be futile?

Comment: It could be she is going to run as a way to impact the presidential race and I have seen a few articles suggesting that

Comment: She lost by a  35-point margin, as I understand. Somewhat similar to the +43 margin Trump had in the state, IIRC

Comment: Yes. But who is going to vote for her, as she is no longer the darling of the crossover voters (Dems voted for her at GOP's primary).

Comment: @r13 If that is her goal it would be just to take enough votes away from Trump to impact the results.

Comment: We can probably answer with what the polling says is likely to happen.  But we can't say if she *thinks* it is futile.

Comment: @JoeW Yes, but instead of defeating Trump directly, she dims the GOP's chance to send a representative to the house. she couldn't afford to alienate Wyoming GOP voters If she's seriously considering a run on 2024, which is the real battleground for the two enemies.

Comment: @r13 This is about Trump and the presidential election as she said she is considering a run for that office. Also it is more about preventing Trump from becoming president then who actually wins the election.

Comment: @JoeW Citing the OP: "Why isn’t Cheney planning to keep her seat by running as an independent (**against Harriet Hageman, a pro-Trump candidate, will be the Republican nominee in November**.)?"" ""**Does Wyoming law prevent her from doing so**, or does she simply think it would be futile?"" Wyoming law will not have effect preventing Liz from running against Trump in the presidential election, but state representative in the coming general election.

Comment: @r13 I think you are missing the point of my statements, she is talking about running for president to impact the race and wanting to run as an independent for her seat in the house isn't even factoring into it.

Comment: @JoeW :) I think you were missing my comment which was directed at the OP's concern - the viability and possibility of Liz, as an independent, vs Harriet Hageman and the Democrat candidate in the upcoming general election.  james K answered correctly.

Comment: @r13 And I think you are missing my very first comment and the first one on the post where I suggest that she is going to be running for president to impact the election and not worry about her current office.

Comment: @JoeW My bad writing, which was directed at the OP, not your comment. Sorry for stirring up this misunderstanding.

Comment: I've heard some political analysts say Liz Cheyne running as an Independent (or more likely a 3rd party candidate) would actually hurt the Democratic party more than the Republican.  The biggest spoiler party for the Republicans is the Libertarian Party and the Libertarians do not like her either.  It's not likely she would be a draw in the 2024 general elections.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Liz Cheney would not be elegible due to Wyoming's sore loser law.

> [WY Stat § 22-5-302 (2014)](https://law.justia.com/codes/wyoming/2014/title-22/chapter-5/article-3/section-22-5-302/)
> 22-5-302. Unsuccessful primary candidates precluded.
>
> An unsuccessful candidate for office at a primary election, whose name is printed on any party ballot, may not seek nomination by petition for the same office at the next general election.

It is unlikely that she would want to anyway, her result in the primary puts her in a very weak position. Among Republicans, it is clear that Hageman is preferred by a margin of 2:1. And some of Cheney's republican supporters would not vote for her in the General for fear of allowing the Democratic party candidate to win.

Democrats (a minority in Wyoming) would be unlikely to support Cheney, apart from her Anti-trump stand, most of the rest of her policies are fairly conventional Republican policies (Remember her criticism of environmental groups). And for the same reason, Cheney is very unlikely to switch to the Democratic party, she simply isn't a supporter of the wider Liberal platform of the party.

Independents might support Cheney, but there are not enough to give her the win. Only about 1/8 of voters identify as unaffiliated.

And if she has ambitions to be President, running as a spoiler is not likely to win support among the conservative sector of the American public.

Comment: My previouis answer was incorrect, as pointed out but JoeW

Comment: "Only about 1/8 of voters identify as unaffiliated." Is this among Wyoming voters or general voters in the United States?  In the U.S., as a rule, "swing" voters represent slightly above 1/3rd of the voter base while both parties are slightly below 1/3rd of the base.

Comment: I forget to transfer the source from the other answer: See https://sos.wyo.gov/Elections/Docs/VRStats/2022/22JanVR_Stats.pdf